# Jquery / PHP - ajax post and encoding

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I m trying to send a url string using ajax post but dont not know why the string is auto encoding (%25) or omitting

url = http://www.domain.com.br/berco-elegance-wave-verde-ayoba%2521-6343.html

php receive:
http://www.domain.com.br/berco-elegance-wave-verde-ayoba%21-6343.html

I check with Firebug the post data and the url string is already changed: 
POST DATA
url: http://www.domain.com.br/berco-elegance-wave-verde-ayoba%21-6343.html

My jquery code:

```
function save_competitor() {
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/storeproduct/insert_competitor",
    data: "url="+$("#url"),
    dataType:"json",
    contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.success){
            alert('ok');
        }else{
            alert('error');
        }
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        if(status=='parsererror')
            window.location.href = 'auth/login/';
    }
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="http://www.domain.com.br/berco-elegance-wave-verde-ayoba%2521-6343.html"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL Endoding References:

```
space   %20
    !   %21
    "   %22
    #   %23
    $    %24
    %   %25
    &   %26
    '   %27
    (   %28
    )   %29
    *   %2A
    +   %2B
    ,   %2C
    -   %2D
    .   %2E
    /   %2F
   .....
```

**[encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)** and **[decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)** will resolve this issue

```
encodeURIComponent(url);
decodeURIComponent(url)
```

Comment: Hi LearneR. The url string is already encoded. I dont want ajax chage the content in post.

Comment: I tried to use encodeURIComponent and is working... i will try other ulrs... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

isnt $("#url") returning an Element?

```
$("#url").val()
or
$("#url").attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

You get your `data` from html text already encoded. Can you show us what the part of your $("#url") html code look like ?

EDIT :

Function :

```
function urldecode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent((str+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
}
```

Usage :

`data: "url="+urldecode($("#url").text());`

Comment: Hi. Is a <input type="text" value="http://www.domain.com.br/berco-elegance-wave-verde-ayoba%2521-6343.html" id="url" name="url"/>

Comment: @adrianogf -- Edited : Please report if you problem is solved !